# Open script in a virtual tty like vi or vim

Tags: bash, shell, vim

I try to make a script that will display content of a file ( like  a watch cat or a tail -f ).

for this, i currently just do a clear, cat myfile, sleep 2, and then repeat it.

i want it to be in a "virtual tty"or thing like that, but i don't want install any package (like screen), i want to open a virtual tty like vi do ( if you do vi myfile, it will display it in "an other tty" and when you leave it, you get your tty back).

I'm doing just for fun, for learning so i really want to find a way without install a package.

Thanks for help and sorry about my english !

Comment: The common name of the feature used by Vim is "alternate screen". Look up `smcup`/`rmcup`.

Comment: Know little about "virtual tty". But for learning purposes, maybe you can find a popular open-source package and find out how it works by its source code.